# Unity-NullReferenceException When Using Composite Design Pattern

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, composite

So I'm trying to make a simple dialogue tree in the form of a composite design pattern, where each member of the hierarchy has basically the same customizable properties, in this case, a question and two options. In Unity, I'm trying to assign the question to a textbox and each option into a button. When you click a button, you go to another level of the tree, or a leaf. For whatever reason, I'm getting the null reference exception error and its pointing to this line. I'll try my best to answer any further questions.

> ```
>         Textbox.GetComponent<Text>().text = question;
> ```

It might be something simple I can fix, but I'm not really sure where to look right now. If anyone could help me in the right direction, I would very much appreciate it. Thank you. Here is my script for the levels in the composite pattern.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Composite : MonoBehaviour {


    private void Start()
    {

        Level Level1 = new Level("Hello", "Hi", "Shut Up");
        Level leaf1 = new Level("Don't be Rude");

        Level Level2 = new Level("What you Doing?", "Not Much", "None of your Business");
        Level leaf2 = new Level("Well Excuuuuse Me");

        Level Level3 = new Level("Can I do that too?", "Sure", "Go Away");
        Level leaf3 = new Level("Fine. Be a Jerk");

        Level Level4 = new Level("This is boring, can we do something else?", "Why not?", "You're boring");
        Level leaf4 = new Level("I'll go be boring somewhere else");

        Level Level5 = new Level("You want ice cream?", "Sounds Good", "I'm allergic");
        Level leaf5 = new Level("ok.......");
        Level leaf = new Level("I Want Chocolate");



        Level1.add(Level1);
        Level1.add(leaf1);

        Level2.add(Level3);
        Level2.add(leaf2);

        Level3.add(Level4);
        Level3.add(leaf3);

        Level4.add(Level5);
        Level4.add(leaf4);

        Level5.add(leaf5);
        Level5.add(leaf);

    }


    public class Level
    {
        public static Text Textbox;
        public static Text Button1;
        public static Text Button2;

        public string OptionA;
        public string OptionB;
        public string Question;

        public string Leaf;

        private List<Level> levels;

        public Level(string question, string optionA, string optionB)
        {
            this.Question = question;
            this.OptionA = optionA;
            this.OptionB = optionB;


            Textbox.GetComponent<Text>().text = Question;
            Button1.GetComponent<Text>().text = OptionA;
            Button2.GetComponent<Text>().text = OptionB;


            levels = new List<Level>();

        }


        public Level(string leaf)
        {
            this.Leaf = leaf;
            Textbox.text = leaf;
        }

        public void add(Level lvl)
        {
            levels.Add(lvl);
        }

        public List<Level> getLevels()
        {
            return levels;
        }

    }

}
```

Initializer Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Initializer : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text Textbox;
    public Text Button1;
    public Text Button2;

    void Awake()
    {
        Composite.Level.Textbox = this.Textbox;
        Composite.Level.Button1 = this.Button1;
        Composite.Level.Button2 = this.Button2;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your `Textbox` instance is not getting initialized.  In the ctor for `Level` you call `Textbox.GetComponent<Text>().text = question;`  but `Textbox` is not initialized.  It is likely null.  The same is likely true for `Button1` and `Button2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it looks pretty straight forward.

You are creating new instances of the level Class, but never set the `Text`and `Button` property.

This part is also redundant, because you are telling it to find a reference of itself! ("Textbox" is of type `Text`)

```
Textbox.GetComponent<Text>()....
```

To fix your nullreference, you could make the fields static.

```
public static Text Textbox;
public static Text Button1;
public static Text Button2;
```

And assign them from somewhere else. Maybe an initializer script with public fields? You could do a lot of different things.
Here is an example where you add this script to an empty gameobject, then drag the textbox/ buttons into the inspector slots:

```
public class Initializer : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Text Textbox;
   public Button Button1;
   public Button Button2;

 // Awake is called before Start, so Start() in your Composite script will be called 
 // after these fields have been initialized
   void Awake() 
   {
      Level.Textbox = this.Textbox;
      Level.Button1 = this.Button1;
      Level.Button2 = this.Button2;
   }
}
```

finally Remove these commented lines, they do exactly the same.

```
    // Textbox.GetComponent<Text>().text = question;
    Textbox.text = question;
    Button1.GetComponent<Text>().text = optionA;
    // Button1.text = optionA;
    Button2.GetComponent<Text>().text = optionB;
    // Button2.text = optionA;
```

Comment: I made some edits in my question. I also created an initializer script, but I'm still getting a null reference error and it points to this line             Button1.GetComponent<Text>().text = OptionA;

Comment: Did you drag the Text and Button objects into the corresponding field on the Initializer MonoBehaviour? Also, try moving the "Level class" into a seperate file.